# Update multiple ActiveRecord objects in a Ruby block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update multiple ActiveRecord by iterating over a list of ActiveRecord objects. How do I get the `.save` method to work properly within the block?

Here are the models:

```
class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
   has_many :missions, through: :jobs
end

class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
   has_many :floors, through: :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :floor
   has_and_belongs_to_many :mission
end
```

So, a Floor has many jobs and a job can have many Missions. In order to for a Mission to be eligible, all Floors must be owned. For a given floor, I want to find all possible missions, determine if the mission is_eligible, and set is_eligible accordingly. Here is the code:

```
class FloorsController < ApplicationController
   include FloorsHelper

   def update
       # find current floor and update is_owned
       @floor = Floor.find(params[:id])
       @floor.is_owned = !@floor.is_owned
       @floor.save

       # find all missions for current floor
       @mission = Mission.joins(:floors).where("floors.id = ?", params[:id]).readonly(false)
       @mission.each do |mission_hash|
         # for a mission, return a list of all floors needed
         floors = Floor.joins(:missions).where(['mission_id = ?', mission_hash.id])
         mission_hash.is_eligible == mission_is_eligible(floors)
         mission_hash.save
       end
       redirect_to root_url
   end
```

The logic works, but I can't get the ActiveRecord methods to work within the `@mission.each do |mission_hash|` block. Here is the console output (with some notes inline):

```
Started PATCH "/floors/20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-11 14:32:10 -0700
Processing by FloorsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"oWULNXCZeUJnX0MDt6cWyxOeiLduFE/F4KWz8v79v30=", "id"=>"20"}

### Floor is found and updated correctly ###
  Floor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "floors".* FROM "floors" WHERE "floors"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "20"]]
   (23.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (10.8ms)  UPDATE "floors" SET "is_owned" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "floors"."id" = 20  [["is_owned", false], ["updated_at", Fri, 11 Jul 2014 21:32:10 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT

### Find all missions for a given floor ###
  Mission Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "missions".* FROM "missions" INNER JOIN "jobs_missions" ON "jobs_missions"."mission_id" = "missions"."id" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "jobs_missions"."job_id" INNER JOIN "floors_jobs" ON "floors_jobs"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" INNER JOIN "floors" ON "floors"."id" = "floors_jobs"."floor_id" WHERE (floors.id = '20')

### Now moving through the block to find each Floor ###
  Floor Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "floors".* FROM "floors" INNER JOIN "floors_jobs" ON "floors_jobs"."floor_id" = "floors"."id" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "floors_jobs"."job_id" INNER JOIN "jobs_missions" ON "jobs_missions"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" INNER JOIN "missions" ON "missions"."id" = "jobs_missions"."mission_id" WHERE (mission_id = 22)

### This is the output for mission_is_eligible() ###
  false

### PROBLEM IS HERE ###
### No UPDATE command? Why U No Update??? ###
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT

### Repeat loop ###
  Floor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "floors".* FROM "floors" INNER JOIN "floors_jobs" ON "floors_jobs"."floor_id" = "floors"."id" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "floors_jobs"."job_id" INNER JOIN "jobs_missions" ON "jobs_missions"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" INNER JOIN "missions" ON "missions"."id" = "jobs_missions"."mission_id" WHERE (mission_id = 50)
false
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
       (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 38.4ms)
```

Comment: Is there anything changing in the mission when you are saving it? Try touching updated_at before saving - mission_hash.update_attribute(:updated_at,Time.now)

Comment: Changed this line in the controller: `mission_hash.update_attribute(:is_eligible, mission_is_eligible(floors))` and added `mission_hash.update_attribute(:updated_at,Time.now)`. :updated_at is working, but is_elgible becomes null.

Comment: what is datatype of is_eligible? Is it a enum/boolean/integer?

Comment: are you using == for assignment here -   mission_hash.is_eligible == mission_is_eligible(floors)

Comment: It works! There was a bug in the mission_is_eligible() helper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of == use = for assignments

```
mission_hash.is_eligible = mission_is_eligible(floors)
mission_hash.save
```

OR use update_attribute

```
mission_hash.update_attribute(:is_eligible, mission_is_eligible(floors))
```